# How to get Export-Csv to output same information as screen output?

Tags: powershell

```
Get-WmiObject -list | where-object {$_.name -match "win32"} | Select-Object 
name,methods,properties
```

This displays the name, methods and properties of each Win32 class and I wanted to get this information into a CSV file.

The following however outputs doesn't output the same information.

```
Get-WmiObject -list | where-object {$_.name -match "win32"} | Select-Object 
name,methods,properties | Export-CSV "c:\output.csv"
```

How can I do this?

(Updated my script as it had an error.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some extra manual work and make sure you expand the names and join them by some delimiter:

```
$methods = @{n='Methods';e={ ($_.Methods | select -expand Name) -join ';'}}
$properties = @{n='Properties';e={ ($_.Properties  | select -expand Name) -join ';'}}

Get-WmiObject -List | 
Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Win32_*"} | 
Select-Object Name,$methods,$properties | 
Export-Csv .\win32.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: By the way, in ps 2.0 and above you can get the classes without a using where-object: Get-WmiObject -List Win32_*

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that each WMI Object has properties that themselves are arrays and Output-CSV can't really handle that.

To fix this, you'd need to handle the arrays of arrays explicitly.

WHat specifically do you want to be output?